# facing problem in downloading the audio data of a trimmed youtube video using youtube-dl and ffmpeg libraries

Tags: python, ffmpeg, youtube-dl, os.system, anaconda3

I'm trying to download the audio content of a trimmed YouTube video using youtube-dl (v2021.12.17) and FFmpeg (v4.2.2) libraries in python, on Windows 10 PC. I am able to download the audio data when the command is executed on the Pycharm terminal, but not able to download the same content when using os.system() command.

For example, I'm able to download the data when I execute

```
"ffmpeg -ss 30 -t 10 -i $(youtube-dl -f best -g https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3NGZcpAZcl0) -- output1.wav"
```

command on the Pycharm terminal.

But, i'm getting an error, when I try to execute the same in the Editor window as shown below,

```
os.system('ffmpeg -ss 30 -t 10 -i $(youtube-dl -f best -g https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3NGZcpAZcl0) -- output1.wav')

error: $(youtube-dl: No such file or directory
```

I also tried enclosing the $() link in quotes and then executed it. But, after doing this, I am getting a different error as shown below

```
os.system('ffmpeg -ss 30 -t 10 -i "$(youtube-dl -f best -g https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3NGZcpAZcl0)" -- output1.wav')

error: $(youtube-dl -f best -g https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3NGZcpAZcl0): Invalid argument
```

So, can any of you help me in resolving this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because your command is actually a shell script inserting a string from another system call by `$(...)`. Python's `os.system()` can run only one shell command at a time (based on observation).

What does this mean? You need to run `youtube-dl` and `ffmpeg` commands separately with `subprocess`:

```py
import subprocess as sp

# run youtube-dl and capture its output as a string
results = sp.run(['youtube-dl','-f','best','-g',
                  'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3NGZcpAZcl0'],
                 stdout=sp.PIPE,universal_newlines=True)
url = results.stdout

# run ffmpeg
sp.run(['ffmpeg','-ss','30','-t','10','-i', url, 'output1.wav')
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I tried executing as you suggested, but, I couldn't get the output.wav file. I'm getting an i/o error after executing ffmpeg command i.e.,

[tls @ 0000028a28834ec0] Error in the pull function
: I/O error

I searched on internet to resolve this issue, but couldn't. So, can you help me further?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's a PATH problem.
Try specifying the full path of youtube-dl:

```
os.system('ffmpeg -ss 30 -t 10 -i $(/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl -f best -g https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3NGZcpAZcl0) -- output1.wav')
```

Comment: I tried giving the full path of youtube-dl, but, it couldn't solve the problem. I'm still getting an invalid argument error. By the way, i'm using a conda environment